# Why wait() is not working after notifyAll() is invoked

Tags: java, multithreading, tags, wait, notify

i don't know what should do! i am a beginner,
`public void checkUp(){}` worked fine, but inside method `notifyAll()` will not notify to the `wait()`.

```
public class Doctor extends Thread {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Doctor doctor = new Doctor();
        Patient patient1 = new Patient(doctor);
        Patient patient2 = new Patient(doctor);
        patient1.setName("Patient One");
        patient2.setName("Patient Two");
        patient1.start();
        patient2.start();
   }
}
```

//This is Patient Class

```
class Patient extends Thread {
    Doctor d;
    static boolean isAlready = false;

    public Patient(Doctor d) {
        this.d = d;
    }

    public void run() {
        synchronized(this) {
            if (isAlready == false) {
                isAlready = true;
                try {
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " Wait to see Doctor\n");
                    wait();
                    checkup();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
            checkup();
        }

    }

    public void checkup() {
        synchronized(this) {
            try {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " Enter Doctor's Room!\n");
                System.out.println("After Consulting Doctor! '" + Thread.currentThread().getName() + "' Paid fees to Doctor\n");
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " Notify to next Patient to enter Doctor's Room!\n");
                notifyAll();
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " Leaves Hospital\n");

            } catch (Exception e) {

            }

            isAlready = false;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: hi there, welcome, you should try to give as much info as possibe

Comment: When does the `checkup` method is being called (except in `run` method) ?

Comment: All your patients wait until another patient calls 'notifyAll'...

So no patient calls notifyAll, never (because all patients are waiting)... XD

Comment: If you want to synchronize many `Patient`s, you need to use shared object instead of `this`. Now, `notifyAll()` notifies only threads that waits on monitor of one particular `Patient` object, not all of them.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are trying to share common resource (Doctor) across different threads (Patient), In this case you need to get lock on common object that is Doctor not Patient.

Try this.

```
class Patient extends Thread {
    Doctor d;
    public Patient(Doctor d) {
        this.d = d;
    }
    public void run() {
        synchronized (d) {
            checkup();
        }
    }
    public void checkup() {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()
                + " Enter Doctor's Room!\n");
        System.out.println("After Consulting Doctor! '"
                + Thread.currentThread().getName() + "' Paid fees to Doctor\n");
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()
                + " Notify to next Patient to enter Doctor's Room!\n");
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()
                + " Leaves Hospital\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks pradeep!! but i just learn about wait and notify! so only i wrote a program!! but it wont work properly

Comment: Problem with your code, there are two threads and each calling wait on itself (this), After calling wait on certain object other thread need to call notify/notifyAll on the same object to awake the waiting thread.

Answer (score 0):

You have two Patient objects, and each one only `wait()`s or `notifyAll()`s itself.  If a Patient object enters a `wait()` call, who is going to notify it?

---

You are trying to model a queue:  There is one doctor, and there are many patients who must each wait their turn to see the doctor.

By associating a thread with each patient, and by blocking each patient thread until its turn comes up, you are exploiting the hidden queues that the operating system uses to implement thread synchronization.

Why not use an explicit queue instead?  Why not represent patients by objects in a queue, and model the doctor by a thread that picks patient objects from the queue one-by-one and serves them?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Patient extends Thread{
Doctor d;
    static boolean isAlready = false;

    public Patient(Doctor d) {
        this.d = d;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Doctor doctor = new Doctor();
        doctor.start();
}   
    public void run() {
        synchronized (d) {
        //  System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" Runn\n");
            if (isAlready == false) {
                try {
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+ " Wait to see Doctor\n\n");
                    isAlready = true;
                    d.wait();
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                    checkup();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }else{
                checkup();
            }
        }

    }
    public  void checkup() {
        synchronized (d) {
            try {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+ " Enter Doctor's Room!\n");
                System.out.println("After Consulting Doctor! '"+ Thread.currentThread().getName()+ "' Paid fees to Doctor\n");
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+ " Notify to next Patient to enter Doctor's Room!\n");
                d.notify();
                isAlready = false;
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+ " Leaves Hospital\n");

            } catch (Exception e) {

            }

            }
    }

}


class Doctor extends Thread {
    public void run(){

        String patientName[] ={"Aravi","Elaa","Sethu","Bala","Ram","Sharukazen","Sathish","Gold"};
        Patient[] patients=new Patient[patientName.length];
        Doctor doctor = new Doctor();
        for (int i =0; i<patientName.length;i++){
        patients[i] = new Patient(doctor);
        patients[i].setName(patientName[i]);
        patients[i].start();
        }

}
```

}

finally i found the Answer.thank you guys!

Answer (score 0):

Both threads will call `wait()` and wait there forever before ever calling `checkup()`. Since both threads are waiting, neither can continue to `checkup()`and call `notifyAll()` from within it.